# Use website "url" as key in firebase

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-schema, database

When I want to use URL (e.g., www.abc.com/1234), I got an error:

```
First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".
```

Looks like in a schema-less database, URL cannot be used as key?  What are my options?  I still need to efficiently search the website object using URL as a key.  I don't want to query everything and loop through them myself.

This is my intended design.

```
{
  "websites": [
    {
      "www.abc.com/1234": {
        "visits": 100,
        "likes": 20
      }
    },
    {
      "www.abc.com/8888": {
        "visits": 300,
        "likes": 30
      }
    },
    {
      "www.uber.com/jobs": {
        "visits": 400,
        "likes": 50
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebase's push IDs as your keys and store the website URL as a property. For example:

```
{
    "websites": {
        "-KCm4eCdDOiOqYU30y_a": {
            "url": "www.abc.com/1234",
            "visits": 100,
            "likes": 20
        },
        "-KCm3gJvnsvAi9qRMqv_": {
            "url": "www.abc.com/8888",
            "visits": 300,
            "likes": 30
        },
        "-KCm3f4lB1nIZKDSeXFG": {
            "url": "www.uber.com/jobs",
            "visits": 400,
            "likes": 50
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you need to get a specific child based on its url, you can use `orderByChild('url').equalTo('www.uber.com/jobs')` for example. [Docs on complex queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries).

Comment: This solution is good but it requires a round trip to Firebase, an `orderByChild` query and requires the client to be online. Below I proposed an alternative that avoids these issues.

Answer (score 2):

@Anid Monsur's solution is good but it requires a round trip to Firebase, an `orderByChild` query and requires the client to be online.

I propose an alternative solution that hashes the URL and store the hash as the key:

```
{
  "websites": {
    "hash('www.abc.com/1234')": {
      "url": "www.abc.com/1234",
      "visits": 10, 
      "likes": 20
    }
  }
}
```

It's up to you to choose an appropriate hashing function.

This solution's primary benefit is performance - getting the key given the URL no longer requires a round trip to Firebase (or the `orderByChild` query for that matter) but rather just a quick hash:

```
const key = hash(url);
```

The benefit becomes more obvious if you need to use URL `id`s in subsequent queries (eg. many-to-many relationships).

The secondary benefit is your application can do stuff with the URL `id`s while it's offline. The proposed solution by @Anid Monsur works great only while you are online.

Comment: what hash function would be appropriate to hash urls?